# iOS "swipe to delete" not changing edit button state

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've got a `UITableView` which has been created programatically. I'm now trying to add the ability to delete the rows using the edit mode.

I've added the default way of doing this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

When you tap the button, it enters edit mode and the button changes to the 'done' button.

However, when I "slide to delete" the row, which just shows the delete button, the existing edit button doesn't change to 'done'.

Is there something I need to do extra because I created the table view programatically?

Below is the code for my tableview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.voucherTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 36, 320, self.view.frame.size.height - 36) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.voucherTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.voucherTableView.delegate = self;
    self.voucherTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.voucherTableView];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

}

// Default table view data source methods go here

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.voucherTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Commit the delete
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  Usually delete is accomplished either with the delete button on the left, or by swipe/slide to delete.  In either case you should be getting a "Delete" button to confirm.  The "Done" button has nothing to do with delete, that just exits edit mode.  It would also be helpful to see the complete setup for your tableview.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am getting the "Delete" button for both types of edit, but it's the original "Edit" button which isn't changing to "Done" when you do the "slide to delete". I've added my code to my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my answer for you:  the button doesn't change to "Done" because a slide to delete does not actually have to be done in "Edit" mode and it does not put you into edit mode.

You could force it into Edit mode if you wish when you perform the delete, not sure why you would want to do that?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        [tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        // Commit the delete
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realise it's not meant to. I think I must have assumed because on the "Messages" app, if you "slide to delete" it changes the edit button to done, obviously they must do this manually. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, it is a little bit inconsistent.  Glad to help :)

Comment: Apple's docs for `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` specifically say **"You should not call setEditing:animated: within an implementation of this method. If for some reason you must, invoke it after a delay by using the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method."**

Comment: @BenLachman  Clearly things have changed in 3 yrs -- perhaps you should put up an updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

**New functionality, current as of iOS 8**

As long as you use `self.editingItem` it should now update correctly on its own. In fact, Apple's documentation for `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` now specifically says:

> You should not call `-setEditing:animated:` within an implementation of this method. If for some reason you must, invoke it after a delay by using the `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method.

This is a change from the previous functionality that is mentioned in some of the other answers.

One caveat to note is that, as of iOS 8.1.2, if you fail to call `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` in `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` (for instance by calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` after updating your data model instead) the editingItem will be stuck in the *edit* state.

Answer (score 0):

@Scrooby: The edit button title and state won't change to "Done"

That is because "Edit" button click triggers editing mode of tableview, but the editing mode of the tableview does not trigger event to change button title to "Done".

Suppose Edit Button Click (Event A) & TableView in Editing Mode (Event B)

Event A implies Event B, but Event B does not imply Event A.

Hope you get it now. This is a simple logic.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting  `[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];` at the end of the method instead. It should work then.